# How to reset inputFieldValue of PrimeNG calendar

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-calendar

I am using PrimeNG `p-calendar` with `selectionMode` multiple.

When user selects more than 4 dates, the text in the input is too long and becomes hidden.

I want to set the input value so that if more than 4 dates were selected, it will show the first 4 dates and a character like "(+)" or "..." etc.

I tried to set the input value in the `onselect` event but it doesn't work:

```
@ViewChild('multiDate', undefined) private multiDate:any;

public onDateSelect(selectedDate:any){
     this.multiDate.inputfieldViewChild.nativeElement.value += "(+)";
     this.multiDate.inputfieldValue += "(+)";
}
```

Any Ideas?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to set `text-overflow: ellipsis;` to PrimeNG `p-inputtext` class:

```
:host ::ng-deep {
  .p-inputtext {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
  }
}
```

See [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-calendar-demo-kv5cnz?file=src/app/app.component.scss)